# Test case in case of check event angular2

Tags: angular, testing

Have a click event on check input,

```
<input class="check-input" (click)="onCheck($event, obj)">

onCheck(event: ElementRef, checkObj){

}
```

How to write test for this function,

```
let ele : HTMLElement;
ele = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.check-input');
ele.click(new Event('checked'),mockingData);
```

It gives me "Supplier parameters do not match any signature of call target".
How do I trigger click event on this?

Answer (score 1):

The function has param event with incorrect type assigned. The argument is of type Event and not ElementRef. Change it to follow:

```
onCheck(event: Event, checkObj){

}
```

Comment: Buddy, I have to use event['target'] and event['target'].parentNode, which is not possible if I use type as Event, but it these are present if event type is made ElementRef. But that is not the issue, if .ts has event in parameter, how do I send that in parameters in testing. Even if I use component = fixture.componentInstance; and component.onCheck(), how do I pass event parameter?